# What is an "avuncle-off"?

Tags: idioms

In Adrian Tshaikovsky's book [Shards of Earth](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/56616571-shards-of-earth)

> For a moment Solace though the pair were going to have an avuncle-off right here at the table.

Even if I know that an "avuncle" is [a mother's brother](https://theweek.com/articles/453027/11-littleknown-words-specific-family-members), "avuncle-off" can probably only be translated by a native speaker who grew up in the right region.

So my question is: What on earth do you do with an "avuncle-off"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141876/discussion-on-question-by-meisterplanlos-what-is-an-avuncle-off).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is probably a combination of *avuncle* and *face-off*.

In Merriam-Webster, a *[face-off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/face-off)* is a confrontation. *Avuncle*, which can mean uncle, is related to *[avuncular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avuncular)*, meaning to be "suggestive of an uncle especially in kindness or geniality."

The combination of the two would suggest a competition related to who can be more *avuncular*, that is, who can be more like an uncle either literally or in general demeanor.

It's a neologism, not a set phrase. Similar neologisms referring to roles like *[friend-off](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Friend-Off)* exist. There are other examples of words with *-off* meaning competition:

- [cook-off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cook-off), a cooking competition (see also [bake-off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Bake-Off))
- [runoff](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/runoff), a final race or election after an initial race
- [dance-off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dance-off), a dance competition

Comment: Out of the context of the passage in the book this sounds quite reasonable. Thanks! :)